# Как мне получить два значения tokens в bat файле?

Tags: cmd, bat

Я использую Windows OS
У меня есть одна строчка INPUT, я ввожу туда значения.
Получать одно значение мне удаётся если я указываю tokens=*
Но мне теперь нужно получить два значения из этого INPUT и записать их в разные переменные.
В таком вот примере оба введёных значения записываются в одну переменную.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
    set "color=%%p"
    set "opacity=%%z"
)
```

Comment: Буквы генерируются по алфавиту. Вместо `%%z` следует использовать `%%q`. И следует указать `delims`, а не оставлять его пустым, ибо при этом вся строка воспринимается как один токен. Если это пробел или табуляция, следует `delims` вообще убрать.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%p in ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
    set "color=%%p"
    set "opacity=%%q"
)
```

Comment: Благодарю за поддержку! Всё заработало.. 
Буду знать теперь как использовать